# How to override <MTableBody /> in drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to implement drag and drop for the material UI table (https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable).
Below code is working fine but the problem is "div" tag in the below code messing up my table (css).
I don't want to give "ref" in the "div" tag instead I want to update in table body.

Kindly help me with the same.

Using "react-beautiful-dnd" for drag and drop.

```js
Body: (props) => (
              
    
    <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
                <Droppable droppableId="droppable">
                  {(provided) => (
                     <div ref={provided.innerRef}>
                      <MTableBody {...props}/>
                       {provided.placeholder}
                     </div>
                  )}
                </Droppable>
              </DragDropContext>
              ),
```